# Moving project online broke laravel controller

Tags: laravel, class, controller, http-method

That's my route:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=>['auth','role:admin']], function () {

  Route::get('/co2index', 'UserController@adminCo2Index');
}
```

This is the controller method that fails:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Impl\ReferentManager;
use App\Http\Impl\RoleManager;
use App\Http\Impl\UserManager;
use App\Http\Impl\ValidationRulesManager;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Notifications\UserActivatedNotification;
use App\Models\Vendita;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Referent;
use App\Models\Ddt;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function adminCo2Index()
    {
        $search = \Request::get('search'); //<-- we use global request to get the param of URI
        $companies = User::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->orderBy('name')
            ->paginate(10);
        $ddts_count = DB::table('ddts')
            ->select('company_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('company_id')
            ->get();

        if ($companies && $ddts_count) {
            return view('administration.co2Index')->with('companies', $companies)->with('ddts_count', $ddts_count);

        } else {
            return view('administration.co2Index')->with('companies', null)->with('ddts_count', null);

        }
    }
}
```

on my online server if I try to visit:

> mysite.com/admin/co2index
>   it returns:
>    BadMethodCallException Method [adminCo2Index] does not exist. in
>   Controller.php line 82:

On localhost it works! Also, I have other methods on `UserController` class that work even online without any problem!
If I put 'null' on `$companies` or `$ddts_count` the correct empty view is loaded on localhost. If I do the same thing online I have still the same error!
If I put a `dd('ciao')` on the top of the method the error is still showed and no message on front end...

This looks very strange to me! I can't see any typos... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hit this command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: u made my day! thanks! when i move the project i run composer install/composer update then, generating new app key then php artisan clear on route,cache,view. So whats that about? thanks again

Comment: It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php)

Comment: composer install/composer update just installing and updating dependencies

Comment: hold on, next one problem is that the login route now is broken! but Auth routes and view both present!!!! re-run same command suggested didnt fix that

Comment: all the path view auth seem to be missing!

Comment: try php artisan view:clear      and   php artisan route:clear

Comment: if possible share you live link