# auth conflict with some artisan commands

Tags: php, laravel, routes

if ive these:

[image]

and in route file:

[image]

so why ive to see this:

[image]

the page login.blade.php
do not extends any layout, so should be visible i imagine!

I just run some commands to configure the enviroment:
composer dump-autoload (as described here to solve the problem 1 [sol to a previus problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375916/moving-project-online-broke-laravel-controller/55376146?noredirect=1#comment97475382_55376146))
then in order:
-php artisan config:cache
-php artisan route:cache

After that the login page disappear!
How can i solve this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your whole cache

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```